# Error metodo post Requests en python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, post

Estoy haciendo un script que me haga un método `POST`. Sigo la documentación de la librería `requests`. Tengo que hacer un login; cuando utilizo el metodo `GET` no surge ningun error. Consiste en varias etiquetas con *enable* (`value=1`) y *disable* (`value=0`), y al final del formulario tiene una etiqueta *aplicar cambios*. En fin tengo esto:

```python
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json


x = {
    "MbssIndexChanged":1,
    "GuestkEnable":1,
    "GuestServiceSetIdentifier":"guest",
    "commitwlanGuestNetwork":1
}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
session = requests.Session()
r = session.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'), data=json.dumps(x))
```

Y me surge este error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/post.py", line 23, in <module>
    r = session.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user,pass), data=json.dumps(data))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 497, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in
send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host=url, port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /url (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)`
```

He intentado con el `retries=False`, con `verify=False` y sin el `session`, pero sin resultado.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Esto significa que el servidor hacia donde quieres hacer el post te esta cerrando la conexión, ya sea porque estas haciendo demasiadas consultas o porque tu POST esta mal armado.

Por lo general la razon del error te viene dada en el parametro text del objeto r que estas obteniendo al final asi que como ultima linea haz un

```
print r.text
```

Y mira que te dice, quizá es algo trivial. Espero te haya sido útil.